# node.js : Express, socket.io and PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, socket.io

I am using Express, node.js and socket.io. What I would like to implement is a system in which everytime a user connects to the page (upon 'connection' event), an SQL request is performed so the results are emitted to the user by trigerring the event 'get_recipes'. However, after refreshing the page several times, the event 'get recipes' is not triggered anymore... Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code (do I need to log out from the database ? If so, how ?) ? Thanks a lot !

app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var pg = require('pg').native;
var db_URL = "tcp://user1:default@localhost/dbtest";

...

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        pg.connect(db_URL, function(err, client) {      
        client.query("SELECT * FROM Recipes", function(err, results) {
            socket.emit('get_recipes', results);
        });
    });       

});
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but i think, because script is still running, database connecttion event fires only once. you can alter this behavior by changing line order. just try putting pg-connection line before connection handler of io.sockects

Comment: In your case, you're doing a database connection when every user connects to the socket. This may work at the first time but after a period the database may refuse to accept connections. Try moving the `pg.connect` to somewhere not inside the socket connection handler.